# How to Synchronize Timer Event?

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, synchronization

Im developing a c# windows form GUI monitoring application which reads database table and send MAIL and SMS alert.
So in order to monitor database and send mail and SMS i have used c# Timer which get invoked after some seconds,
Once send and mail is sent GUI List box will be updated through a background worker which executes a asynchronous functions.

In the asynchronous function i get database values and spin off two threads to send Mail and SMS.

But if it takes so long, timer thread get over lapped and asynchronous function get overlapped.
So it will send Same Mail several times. How to resolve that? is it happen due to Timer get overlapped?

```
t.Interval = cn.MtimeOut;
t.Enabled = true;
t.Tick += new System.EventHandler(OnTimerEvent);
```

OnTimerEvent implementation

```
private void OnTimerEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lock (_objLock)
    {
        this.startMonitor();
    }
}

private void startMonitor()
{
    MyList = new List<string>();
    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (o, args) => asyncMonitor(); /* function which does sending
                                                 mail SMS and database reading*/

    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (o, args) => UpdateControl();//update list box
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void asyncMonitor()
{
    /* READ DATABASE TABLES AND DO CALCULATIONS 
       WHICH TAKES CONSIDERABLE AMOUNT OF TIME */

    // Thread for sending MAIL by execute MailLogEvent method
    Thread trd = new Thread(MailLogEvent); 

    // Thread for sending SMS by execute SmsLogEvent method
    Thread trd2 = new Thread(SmsLogEvent);

    //parameters for above functions
    trd2.Start(lg);
    trd.Start(lg);
}
```

I even have used lock for Timer event and SMS MAIL sending methods, but it does not synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

i kind of did something similar a few months ago.

create a shared class that maintain which mail is in the queue and make sure you use lock { } and you maintain a uniqueness of the mail in the queue

so if it take too much time and the timer get fire again with the same set of mail(s) it will know that it is present in the queue and wont try to send it again

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to add the "lock" to the database.  With this approach you would add a column like "status" to each SMS/mail to be dispatched.  When the timer retrieves a row and queues it to be sent, it would update the record's status to "pending" or something like that.  Then, when it actually dispatches the message, it would update status to "complete".  Subsequent overlapping timer calls would know not to process records that are in the "pending" state.

Comment: that was one of my option, the problem with it is, what happen if the application crash? you need to reset the state of the record from "pending" to "not sent" which is not difficult but it add let just call it "complexity" to the logic